# Oracle connection not closing in Java Application

Tags: java, oracle, database-connection

I have a connection leak in some older Java web applications which do not utilize connection pooling.
Trying to find the leak is hard because IT will not grant me access to v$session `SELECT Count(*) FROM v$session;`

So instead I am trying to debug with System.out statements.  Even after closing the connection `conn.close();` when I print conn to the System log file it gives me the connection object name.

```
try { 
    Connection conn;
    conn.close() 
    } 
catch (SQLException e) { }
finally { 
    if (conn != null) {
        try {
           System.out.println("Closing the connection"); 
           conn.close();
           }
        catch (Exception ex) 
            {
            System.out.println("Exception is " + ex); 
            }
     }
 }
// I then check conn and it is not null and I can print the object name.
    if (conn != null) {
            System.out.println("Connection is still open and is " + conn); 
    }
```

however if I also add `conn = null;` below the `conn.close();` statement the connection now seems closed.  So my question is does conn.close(); actually release my connection or do I also have to make it null to really release my connection.  Like I said it is really hard for me to determine if the connection is actually released without being able to query v$session.  Is there snippet of java code which can give me my open connections??

It's probably educational at this point because I plan to refactor these applications to use connection pooling but I'm looking for a quick bandaid for now.

Comment: I assume this is slightly contrived, but if you're declaring `conn` inside the `try` block then it's out of scope afterwards, and also in the `finally` block. Still, makes me wonder if you have a class variable that you're shadowing, and maybe somewhere the shadowing is breaking and leaving a leak behind.

Comment: @Alex, you are right... in my actual code, it is declared outside the try.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The important part of the close is what's happening on the database side.  It's the RDBMS that has to close that connection.  Calling the close() method is what communicates the message to the database to close the connection.

Setting the connection to null doesn't instruct RDBMS to do anything.

Same logic applies to ResultSet, which is a cursor on the database side, and Statement.  You need to close those in individual try/catch blocks in the finally block of the method that created them, in reverse order of creation.  Otherwise you'll see errors about "Max cursors exceeded".

Comment: That makes sense and was sort of my suspicion.  OK so after calling close() I tried to reuse the connection and got a java.sql.SQLException: Closed Connection.

Comment: Yeah, you've got to open it, use it, close it.

Answer (score 4):

Setting the conn to null only breaks the reference link to the connection object, and has no influence on the connection being open or not. If the connection is still open then the connection will still be referred to from inside the JDBC driver/connection pool etc...

Setting a variable to null is more telling the garbage collector that it is ok to clean up the original object when it wants to than anything else.

Answer (score 3):

As others are saying, you've got two different concepts here: closing the connecting and tracking the connection in a variable.

To close the connection, call `conn.close()`.  This *will not* set the variable conn to null.  You can test if the connection is open with `conn.isClosed()`.

If you don't care to track the connection in your code any more, you can `conn = null`.  This *does not* immediately close the connection.  I believe the connection will be automatically closed, based on the JDBC [documentation](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#close()) :

> Releases this Connection object's database and JDBC resources immediately instead of waiting for them to be automatically released.

If you choose to go this route, be aware that the garbage collector may not close your connection as quickly as you want, and you may have what appears to be a resource leak; reserved database locks won't be released until the connection is garbage collected.  Certain drivers (I don't know if oracle is one) impose maximum limit to the number of connections that may exist at one time, so leaving open connections can also cause failures to connect, later in the program.

Answer (score 1):

Connection leaks are a best. I think a good strategy is to wrap the getting and releasing of connections in a couple of functions and then always get and release your connections through those functions. Then you can have those functions maintain a list of all open connections, and do a stack trace on the caller of the allocate function. Then have a screen that shows a list of all open connections and where they came from. Run this in a test environment, run around using a bunch of screens, then exit them all so all the connections SHOULD close, then bring up the screen that shows open connectoins, and the villain should be revealed.

Comment: yeah leaks stink....Some of my latest java web apps use a connectionPool and I can see those working (releasing when reaching my set limit) These older java web apps - if you can call java mixed with HTML in a ton of jsp files an application!! - open and close connections in each jsp.  If I am going to modify these jsp pages, I might as well do a full refactor into a MVC with a connectionPool bean.  I am curious as to where my leak is though.

Answer (score 0):

My explanation here is an educated guess.

As a practice I have always set conn=null after the close. I believe when you do conn.close() you are telling the garbage collector that it's ready to be garbage collected. However, it will be up to the garbage collection process to determine when to do so.

Also you can change your

> if(conn!=null)

to

> if (conn.isClosed())

..

Answer (score 0):

Is there snippet of Java code which can give me my open connections?

```
Statement smt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try { 
        // Create Statement from connection
        smt = conn.createStatement();
        // Execute Query in statement 
        rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT 1 FROM Dual");

        if (rs.next()) {
            return true; // connection is valid
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            // Some sort of logging
            return false;
        }
        finally {
            if (smt != null) smt.close();
            if (rs != null) rs.close();
        }
```

Just a quick guess, assuming you are using Oracle.
Sugession: Why don't you install jboss and set up connection pooling through there?

Comment: I work for a 'red tape' corporation - installing software - ha! Good Luck Next to impossible here :)

Comment: not sure how your code will tell me "ALL" my open db connections.  Where is conn decalred?? And if I declare it in your code conn = getConnection();  I will see 1 valid connection.  I want to see something like SELECT Count(*) FROM v$session but IT wont grant me access to v$session

Comment: My code is an alternative to conn.isClosed() but I guess it does not help you here. I think there are two concepts here as some of the others have mentioned, one is an object being assigned a null value and being GCed in the next GC cycle and the other the Connection objects close() method releasing the JDBC connection immediately. If you are determining that the connection is open by checking if the connection object is still present, that may be a false positive in my opinion.